# Listview click event only happens first time with dialog in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, jquery

I am attaching a click event on the listview items, which feeds into a dialog. When I close the dialog and try to click on another item, the click event doesn't happen again. Is there anything wrong with what I have or a better way?

```
        var chapterId;

        $(document).on('click', '.listview', function (e) {
            var source = $(e.target).closest('li');
            var id = source.attr('data-chapter');
            if (id) chapterId = id;
            else chapterId = null;
        });

        $(document).on('pageinit', '#mydialog', function (e) {
            if (chapterId) {
                //DO SOMETHING WITH ID LIKE GET FROM DATABASE
            }
        });
```

This is what my listview looks like:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="listview">
    <li data-chapter="1"><a href="dialog.html" data-rel="dialog">
        <h2>Chapter 1</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </a></li>
    <li data-chapter="2"><a href="dialog.html" data-rel="dialog">
        <h2>Chapter 2</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </a></li>
    <li data-chapter="3"><a href="dialog.html" data-rel="dialog">
        <h2>Chapter 3</h2>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

The first click works and passes the correct Id in the dialog pageinit event, but closing the dialog and clicking another doesn't fire the click (I also tried vclick but same results). Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `'.listview li a'` try using this selector.

Comment: I just tried this but no luck. Seems like the dialog is clearing the events when closing it to go back maybe?

Comment: Are you binding click event to `pageinit`? If yes, remove it. Also. Is `.listview` dynamically added?

Comment: are you closing the dialog properly? if it remains on the page this could be cause the problem. $('#mydialog').dialog('close')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dont use global variables of data-transfer between pages. Use `data` property of the DOM elements. Consider I have a listview like this :

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="songlist" data-theme="c" data-divider-theme="a" data-inset="true">
  <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Song List</li>
  <li data-chapter="1"><a href="#dialogPage">Sweet Child 'O Mine</a></li>
  <li data-chapter="2"><a href="#dialogPage">Summer of '69</a></li>
  <li data-chapter="3"><a href="#dialogPage">Smoke in the Water</a></li>
  <li data-chapter="4"><a href="#dialogPage">Enter Sandman</a></li>
  <li data-chapter="5"><a href="#dialogPage">I thought I've seen everythin</a></li>
```

I have this in a page with id `#mypage1`. The pageinit function of that page will contain your `click` function. Changes :

1. Dont bind the click to the `ul`. Bind it to the `a` tag.
2. Use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the re-direction to happen before u get the chapter Id
3. Store the chapter Id in `data` of `#dialogPage`
4. use `changePage` to redirect.

Here's the code :

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function () {
    $(this).on("click", "#songlist a", function (e) {
        //prevent dialog transition 
        e.preventDefault();
        //get the data-chapter
        var source = $(this).closest("li").attr("data-chapter");
        //set that in #dialogPage's data for later use
        $("#dialogPage").data("chapter", source);
        //redirect to dialog
        $.mobile.changePage(this.href, {
            role: "dialog"
        });
    });
});
```

For the dialog box, I have a markup like this :

```
<div data-role="page" id="dialogPage">
    <div data-role="header">
         <h2>Dialog</h2>

    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

For dialog, changes made :

1. Dont use `pageinit`. that event happens only once, use `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`, which will happen everytime you reach the dialog.
2. get the value of the chapterid from `data` of `#dialogPage` :

   ```
     var chapterId=  $(this).data("chapter");
   ```

Here's the code :

```
//dont use pageinit, use pageshow or pagebefore show for dialog
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#dialogPage", function () {
    //get the chapter Id from data
    var chapterId=  $(this).data("chapter");
    //do anything you want with it.
    $(this).find('[data-role="content"] p').html("<b>Chapter ID : </b>" +));
});
```

And  the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/ZmV5D/3/

Comment: Very elegant and works beautifully - thanks for all the gems!!! I also updated a few typos and errors: http://jsfiddle.net/ZmV5D/3/

Comment: I think you can also use the the data param in $.mobile.changePage and then parse the data-url of the target page: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/

Comment: ok so its not just me.. I said *I think* because I was trying it but couldn't get to work properly (some caching issue). Thanks again!